# Fill array from raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7

I try to fill a array / list from a raw_input but it wont work I cant think of a different way then this :

```
while a != arraycount:
            x = str(raw_input('Please enter file %s to read from :  '%(a)))
            array1[a] = x
            a += 1
```

Do I have to pre-fill the aray/list ?

EDIT : a is a counter for the array space / where it is supposed to go. arraycount is the number of arrays have to be filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't look so advanced, how about using a simple for loop:

```
my_array = []
for i in xrange(number_of_times):
    my_array.append(raw_input('Input: '))

print my_array  # Shows you the results
```

What I have just done is what Jon Clements just showed you without using Python's advanced list-comprehensions. This is simply what that one liner does in the background. Learning list-comprehensions early on will be of great help when you learn to do other things with Python.

To iterate, you can do this:

```
for var in my_array:
   # do something with var, which is a member of my_array.
```

Comment: Does this put it all in one array space or mutipule ? because i need to call them one after one.

Comment: @FierceFuzion: Yes it does. It puts them in one array called `my_array`, and if you want to iterate over them, you simply do a for loop.

Comment: Can i call them like this ? print(array1[1, 2, 3, 4] an so on ?

Comment: @FierceFuzion: Yes, you can but not with commas. If you want the first member, then `array[0]`, the second, `array[1]`. Please note that it starts with a `0`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a list-comp here:

```
a = [raw_input('Please enter: ') for blah in xrange(array_count)]
```

Comment: @Jon-Clements is there a way to filter the input strings(as in reject some based on criteria on the string) in the same line?